# Two dimentional vectors in c++

Tags: c++, vector

How do I use 2D vectors in c++.
I have written the following code but it is not working.I am getting run time error.

```
vector<vector<int> >itemsets;
int main()
{
    itemsets.push_back(vector<int> ());
    itemsets[0].push_back(1);
    itemsets[1].push_back(2);
    cout<<itemsets[0][0]<<itemsets[1][0];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `getting run time error.` where ?

Comment: @Thomas it should print 1 and 2.But it prints nothing and i get error that windows has stopped working(I use code blocks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have pushed only one element in vector `itemsets`.
So you can access only: itemsets[0]. It gives you the first element which is vector you've pushed (let's call it `vector1`).

By executing:

```
itemsets[0].push_back(1);
itemsets[0].push_back(2);
```

you push two elements to `vector1`.

If we represent it as a table it will look like:

```
      col1 col2
row1   1    2
```

You can access elements in `vector1` using [][] where first index is a row and the second is a column:

```
 cout<<itemsets[0][0]<<itemsets[0][1];
```

EDIT:
If you want to add two rows you need to add `vector2` to `itemsets`:

```
itemsets.push_back(vector<int>());  //vector1
itemsets.push_back(vector<int>());  //vector2
itemsets[0].push_back(1);
itemsets[1].push_back(2);
cout<<itemsets[0][0]<<itemsets[1][0];
return 0;
```

Also you can use `std::vector` constructor from `int`:

```
itemsets.push_back(vector<int>(1, 1));  //vector1 push 1 (first parameter is size of vector)
itemsets.push_back(vector<int>(1, 2));  //vector2 push 2
```

Also in C++11 you can add more that one value at once:

```
itemsets.push_back(std::vector<int>({1, 2}));  //vector1
itemsets.push_back(std::vector<int>({3, 4}));  //vector2
std::cout<<itemsets[0][0]<<itemsets[0][1]<<itemsets[1][0]<<itemsets[1][1];
```

Also in C++11 you can initialize your vectors within one row:

```
vector<vector<int> >itemsets = {{1}, {2}}; //add two rows: row1: 1,  and row2: 2.
```